# Is there a way to append a list or text to an existing tex file using pylatex?

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I tried to run `latexTop()` first then `latexMiddle()` but it does not seem to work however it does not show error message it just does not append latexmiddle into latextop ,I also tried `open('name.tex','r') as myfile: text = myfile.read()`

```py
def latexTop():
    doc = Document('name')
    doc.append(Command('title', 'title'))
    doc.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))
    doc.generate_tex()
    #doc.generate_pdf('name',clean_tex=False,compiler='pdflatex')

def latexMiddle(doc):
    doc = Document('name')
    section = Section('Matrix tests')
    subsection = Subsection('Array')
    vec = Matrix(a)
    vec_name = VectorName('a')
    math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
    subsection.append(math)
    section.append(subsection)
    subsection = Subsection('Matrix')
    vec = Matrix(a, mtype='b')
    vec_name = VectorName('a')
    math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
        
    subsection.append(math)
    section.append(subsection)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see why it should append `latexmiddle` into `latextop` - they are two separated functions which create two separated documents. Besides `latexmiddle` get `doc` as argument - `def latexMiddle(doc):` - but later it create totally new document `doc = Document('name')` - but finally it never use this `doc` to add anythink - so finally `latexmiddle` seems totally useless.

Comment: It kind of work now after delete doc = Document('name'), I got confused, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but I think there are big mistakes in code.

1. you have to run `latexMiddle()` inside `latextTop()`

   ```py
   def latexTop():
       doc = Document('name')
       doc.append(Command('title', 'title'))
       doc.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
       doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))

       latexMiddle(doc)

       doc.generate_tex()
       #doc.generate_pdf('name', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdflatex')
   ```
2. `latexMiddle` gets `doc` but later it creates totally new `doc` but finally it make nothing with `doc` - it doesn't append `section` - so all code is useless.

   ```py
   def latexMiddle(doc):
       # doc = Document('name') # DON'T create new document

       section = Section('Matrix tests')

       subsection = Subsection('Array')
       vec = Matrix(a)
       vec_name = VectorName('a')
       math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
       subsection.append(math)
       section.append(subsection)

       subsection = Subsection('Matrix')
       vec = Matrix(a, mtype='b')
       vec_name = VectorName('a')
       math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
       subsection.append(math)
       section.append(subsection)

       doc.append(section)  # <--- append to doc
   ```

---

Eventually you should first create `doc` and later send it to both functions, and finally generate file.

```
def latexTop(doc):   # <--- get doc
    
    doc.append(Command('title', 'title'))
    doc.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))

def latexMiddle(doc):
    # doc = Document('name') # DON'T create new document
    
    section = Section('Matrix tests')
    
    subsection = Subsection('Array')
    vec = Matrix(a)
    vec_name = VectorName('a')
    math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
    subsection.append(math)
    section.append(subsection)
    
    subsection = Subsection('Matrix')
    vec = Matrix(a, mtype='b')
    vec_name = VectorName('a')
    math = Math(data=[vec_name, '=', vec])
    subsection.append(math)
    section.append(subsection)

    doc.append(section)  # <--- append to doc 

#def latexBottom(doc):
#    doc.append( ...something...)

# ---

doc = Document('name')

latexTop(doc) 
latexMiddle(doc)
#latexBottom(doc)
    
doc.generate_tex()
#doc.generate_pdf('name', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdflatex')
```